# " Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В общем проблема такая при запуске вот это ошибка , так как делал по видео в точь точь, где я написал что-то не так?

Это хмл файл activity_main.xml
`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" ></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

`

Это хмл файл row.xml
'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="411dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/off_line_logo" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SongName"
                android:layout_width="328dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SongName"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/SingerName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="SingerName"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

`
Ошибку он выдает на 42 строке в java коде
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот и соответсвенно java сode

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
DatabaseReference mRef;
ImageView mYtbImage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //SetTitle
    actionBar.setTitle("Post List");

    //RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mYtbImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //set layout as LinearLayout
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //send Query to FirebaseDatabase
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference("songsDB");
}
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ander, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Ander, ViewHolder>(
                    Ander.class,
                    R.layout.row,
                    ViewHolder.class,
                    mRef) {


                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Ander model, int position) {
                    viewHolder.setDetails(getApplicationContext(),model.getSongName(),model.getSongSinger(),model.getkzSongytblink());
                    if(model.getkzSongytblink().length()>0){
                        mYtbImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.on_line_logo);
                    }else{
                        mYtbImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.off_line_logo);
                    }
                }
            };

    //SetAdapter to recyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комменту выше ^^. А по сути вопроса - вы разметку не загрузили. Добавьте `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` сразу после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Извините , я тут первый раз вопрос задаю. Теперь буду знать как вопросы задавать

Comment: Cпасибо Юрий , причина была моя не внимательность. Теперь иду решать следующую ошибку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в том , что я по своей невнимательности убрал очень важную строку.

Надо прописать вот это.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);